# creating and killing a thread vs using .notify () and .wait ()

Tags: java, multithreading

Assuming a control thread has access to a bunch of threads and to the objects this thread would wait on. Which one will have a greater impact in performance if I have to start and stop, what several of these threads are doing, from this single control thread ?

Wouldn't it just be better for example to kill it via interruption and just create a new one with the same Runnable?

Comment: Neither `notify()` nor `wait()` are ways to create or kill threads. I think you should go back and read up on the fundamentals a bit. If you like books, Java Concurrency In Practice is a good one.

Comment: `notify()` and `wait()` do not start or stop threads, they are used as part of a [monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) to pause execution and resume it, for synchronization. In addition, the `stop()` method on Java threads is deprecated and may not work, or perform undefined behavior. I would recommend you avoid individual thread objects and use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that you can add Runnable tasks to, and control execution from there.

Comment: yes I know. I guess express it wrong. What I meant is if I had to pause the execution wouldn't it just be better for example to kill it via interrupting it and just create a new one with the same runnable?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating (actually `start()`-ing) a new thread is relatively expensive, so from a performance perspective it would be better to use `wait` / `notify`.

Secondly, `interrupt` is not guaranteed to "stop" a thread.  The thread may choose to ignore the interrupt ... or if it is purely CPU bound, it may not notice it at all.

There is also a third option: use an existing thread pool mechanism.  For example, the ExecutorService API has a various implementations that provided bounded and unbounded thread pools.  These can take care of scaling up and down, and pool shutdown.  You use them by `submit(...)`-ing tasks as `Runnable` instances and you optionally get a `Future` that allows you to wait for the task completion.

Finally, for most concurrent programming use-cases, there are standard classes that support the use-case, and it is better to use them rather than attempting to implement from scratch; e.g. using wait / notify directly.  In your case, you probably need some kind of "barrier" mechanism: `java.util.concurrent.Phaser` might be the one that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are fairly independent from one another and in most cases each thread will know better than the control thread when it's ready to terminate. Killing a thread is very abrupt thing, it's much better to wait for the threat to terminate itself cleanly.